# How to change the default white titlebar of a SWT Window

Tags: java, windows, themes

I'm creating a program thats shoud be dark if the windows appearance settings is set to dark.

I'm using SWT from eclipse

Comment: SWT doesn't have anything to set this. The title bar appearance is controlled by the operating system rather than SWT so this should be automatic.

Comment: @greg-449 but it dont change. Im in dark mode and nothing changes